# Route documents to another site collection if approaching size limit

Tags: 2013, web-part, client-object-model, content-organizer, ssom

We'd like to have a Drop Off library look @ the current site size, and if it is approaching a limit, send the file to a different site within the site collection.  It's kind of like a "you are approaching your size limit...so, send this document somewhere else where's there's room!".

I'm assuming this would be a full Visual Studio approach, and we'd use the SSOM to do this.

As we develop this concept, what about having do deal with multiple site collections (90+ site collections) and keeping this idea manageable?

Do we do event receivers?
Do we create a web part and use the server side object model?
Do we use the REST API or CSOM?

Sounds like for this dynamic document up-loader to be used across MANY site collections, we should do a custom web part users can use at any site collection.

Please advise.

Comment: I am not able to understand your web part solution approach. Can you please elaorate

Comment: Hi Aanchal!  Seems like if we use a webpart, then all site collections on the farm will be able to add this component.  If we need to update anything, it's updated in one place and cascades to all 90+ site collections that may be using this.

Comment: But in Web Part approach, how can it be AUTOMATICALLY, I mean user has to perform some action (click a button) or something.. to activate the server-side code.. isn't it ? I would suggest to create a Timer Job (or multiple timer jobs for each web application - to distribute the work)..

Comment: Yes, we are expecting the user to have to click something as they would with the dropoff library approach + content organizer approach ...you are correct.  We are actually looking at something more size intuitive than the default drop off library.  I like the timer job option, but what about any updates that would need to be made to the time job?  Is it one place to update/maintain code?

Comment: It would also help to mention some of the scope in this project would be to allow the user to choose where the document(s) are going to go if they notice a site collection is filling up...or they have the ability to "override" the content type routing if they don't agree with where the uploaded documents are about to go.